# GroovyClassLoader - adding parsed classes to classpath

Tags: java, groovy, classpath, classloader

I've got a library that allows clients to provide a list of text files, each of which contains groovy code for a class that extends java class Z.  For instance file 'A.groovy' contains

```
package com.mypkg;

public class A extends Z {

    @Override
    public void someMethod() {

        // do something A-ish

    }
}
```

etc.

The library compiles each of these and (in this case) would return to the clients an instance of type Z.

My issue comes when a client needs something like this:

```
package com.mypkg;

public class B extends A {        // extends A!

    @Override
    public void someMethod() {

        // do something B-ish instead of A-ish

    }
}
```

where B extends A, and class A was parsed before class B.

The issue is that the GroovyClassLoader can't seem to find class A, even though it just parsed A.  Here's the code that compiles the scripts and creates the instances:

```
    for (String fileName : listOfScriptFiles) {

        InputStream in = getInputStreamFromFile(fileName);

        CompilerConfiguration compConfig = new CompilerConfiguration();
        GroovyClassLoader classLoader = new GroovyClassLoader(Thread.currentThread()
            .getContextClassLoader(), compConfig);

        Z service = null;

        Class clazz = classLoader.parseClass(in);
        service = (Z) clazz.newInstance();

        return service;
    }
```

Is there a way to 'register' class A with the runtime so that when Groovy tries to compile class B it will not complain that class A doesn't exist?

**UPDATE**

I was actually able to solve this by instantiating the GroovyClassLoader outside the loop that iterates through the client's code list, so the classloader that parses A is the same that parses B.

The question still stands, though, because I could envision a case where in one part of someone's code they parse A, and then in a completely different part, where the same classloader is unavailable, they parse B.

Comment: Can you add a little more detail to your question?  For example, you aren't showing how you defined the variable "in".

Comment: 'in' is just the source code from the list.  Clarified with some context.

Comment: can you add your command that starts the Groovy script?

Comment: The scripts are never 'started'.  They create instances of subclasses of class Z, which are then used in java.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience with the Groovy classloader (which is similar in behavior with Ant and beanshell's classloader in this respect) , you have to decide up front whether you are going to use the default system classloader, in which case you would build the classpath into the command that launches the Groovy script,  OR on the other hand, you specify ONLY the groovy jar on the command line classpath and then you dynamically add classes at the beginning of your Groovy script on the custom classloader.

You aren't providing much information in your question, but my guess is that you put class "A" on the classpath before you launched the script and then your trying to load class "B" dynamically.  That wouldn't work as far as I know.

NOTE: I myself have been trying to figure out how to do this kind of thing.  It seems it would be possible but I still haven't figured it out.